# how to set position of "string painted" in JProgressBar

Tags: java

By default the "string painted" appears at the center of JProgressBar but I want that the "string painted" should appear at the point just after the value of JProgressbar, for example if value of JprogressBar is 0 "string painted" should appears at the extreme left of the JProgressBar, please tell how can I do that???

Answer (score 1):

you need to subclass JProgressBar...

```
private class CustomProgressBar extends JProgressBar{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean isStringToBePainted = false;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(isStringToBePainted ){
            Dimension size = CustomProgressBar.this.getSize();
            int x = (int)( size.width * CustomProgressBar.this.getPercentComplete() );
            int height = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
            int d = g.getFontMetrics().getDescent();
            int y = (size.height + height)/2-d;
            String text = getString();
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK );
            g.drawString(text, x, 12);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setStringPainted(boolean b) {
        // don't do super.setStringPainted(b);
        //super.setStringPainted(b);
        isStringToBePainted=b;
    }
}
```

maybe you play a bit with the font color, i haven't found out where to get the right one...

[image]

Comment: i don't write code for you ...  i gave a nice hint on how to solve your problem...   have a try on your own and if you fail show me what you've achieved and whats is your problem...

Comment: seeing your question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416336/jprogressbar-setstringpaintedtrue-is-painting-two-strings the code abovew might work as well with a vertical progressbar... - but you must switch vertical and horizontal coordinates...